# _this2.renderPrediction is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm new in React Native and I don't understand what is my error and where to locate it.
basically I'm trying to analyse and image to predict what it is. 
I'm using tensorflow and the tutorial I found at this web page https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-48a39185717c.
can someone help me 
here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,StatusBar, ActivityIndicator , TouchableOpacity , Image } from 'react-native'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import { fetch } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'
import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'
import * as jpeg from 'jpeg-js'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'



export default class App extends React.Component {

  //initialisation de isTfReady et isModelReady  à false
  //l'état initial étant qu'ils ne sont pas prêts

  state = {
    isTfReady: false,
    isModelReady: false,
    predictions: null,
    image: null
}

  //récupère la reponse de l'utilisateur sur l'acces à sa camera

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
  if (Constants.platform.ios) {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Désolé , nous avons besoin de votre permission pour accéder à la caméra du téléphone ')
    }
  }
}
  //permet d'attendre que TFJS soit prêt

  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready()
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true
    })

    this.model = await mobilenet.load()
        this.setState({ isModelReady: true })

     this.getPermissionAsync()
  }

  //convertit l'image en tenseur
  //prends en entrée l'image à convertir


  imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
      const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true
      const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY)
      const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3)
      let decallage = 0
      for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
        buffer[i] = data[decallage]
        buffer[i + 1] = data[decallage + 1]
        buffer[i + 2] = data[decallage + 2]

        decallage += 4
      }

      return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3])
    }

    classifyImage = async () => {
      try {
        const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.state.image)
        const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true })
        const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
        const imageTensor = this.imageToTensor(rawImageData)
        const predictions = await this.model.classify(imageTensor)
        this.setState({ predictions })
        console.log(predictions)
      } catch (erreur) {
        console.log(erreur)
      }
    }

    selectImage = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    })

    if (!response.cancelled) {
      const source = { uri: response.uri }
      this.setState({ image: source })
      this.classifyImage()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

  render() {
    const { isTfReady, isModelReady, predictions, image } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.commonTextStyles}>
            TFJS ready? {isTfReady ? <Text>✅</Text> : ''}
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Model ready? </Text>
            {isModelReady ? (
              <Text style={styles.text}>✅</Text>
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator size='small' />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.imageWrapper}
          onPress={ isModelReady ? this.selectImage : undefined}>
          {image && <Image source={image} style={styles.imageContainer} />}

          {isModelReady && !image && (
            <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? '' : 'Predicting...'}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#171f24',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  loadingModelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  imageWrapper: {
    width: 280,
    height: 280,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: '#cf667f',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
    position: 'relative',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
  },
  predictionWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  transparentText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    opacity: 0.7
  },
  footer: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  poweredBy: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#e69e34',
    marginBottom: 6
  },
  tfLogo: {
    width: 125,
    height: 70
  }
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Edit your answer and add it for others to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

renderPrediction is not defined or write in the code. I think you forgot to write the function.

Comment: hi , I thought about what you told me , I understood that I didn't write the function , I thought it was in the library I use , so if I want to write a function who tells me the results of the predictions how should I do it ?

Comment: renderPrediction = prediction => {
    return (
      <Text key={prediction.className} style={styles.text}>
        {prediction.className}
      </Text>
    )
  }